# Sending an email via SendObject I get "Error 2293, the database can't sent this e-mail message"

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I created a database in Access 2016.

It works on the PC I used to develop it.

On three other computers, when trying to send an email via SendObject I get

> "Error 2293, the database can't sent this e-mail message"

This happens if edit is True or False, or if my email client is open or closed.

I tried using different email apps but the Windows default selection seems to make no difference.

On the PC it is working on, it always opens the email in Thunderbird.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

The database is in a Trusted Location. Macros are enabled in Trust Centre. Windows and Office are both up to date. There are no reference library differences. All accounts used have Admin access. Antivirus was disabled for testing.

Many googles. All PCs are running Win10 Pro.

```
Private Sub Command204_Click()
On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim vRecipient As String
    Dim vMsg As String
    Dim vSubject As String

    vMsg = ""
    vSubject = ""
    vRecipient = Me.Text202

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , vRecipient, , , vSubject, vMsg, True
exitOnErr:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then MsgBox "Error (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume exitOnErr
End Sub
```

Ideally the email should open in the default email client. In reality it causes the "Error 2293, the database can't sent this e-mail message".

Comment: Does it give any other error messages before or after Error 2293 or is there a longer message on the errors as the error message you have included could mean quite a range of issues.

Comment: Hi, nope, it gives no other information, and I get no other errors. I tried using a SendDatabaseObject macro. This opens a blank email in the default email client...but without any of the info from the macro..no attachment, subject, to address, etc. A different problem but I thought the extra info may help.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with Outlooks Security Update. This is a list of possible fixes, I'm not sure which will help you as I have no knowledge of your email setup. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/263084/how-to-work-with-the-outlook-e-mail-security-update-in-an-access-datab